# Hard to click anchor tag

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to make a header, for my webpage. The problem is that the three links, to the left that, I've placed with absolute position, are hard to click. It's like the hitbox is very small. I've tried to increase the padding, and set display to block, but neither did work.
[`Code`](https://jsfiddle.net/3x00fzjf/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="sideheader">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="header">
 <h3><a href="index.html">Webpage name</a></h3>
 <hr>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Social Media</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
} 

.sideheader {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:-10px;

}

.sideheader ul {
  color: #000;


}

.sideheader ul li {
  color: #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top:15px;
}

.sideheader ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}



#header {
  margin: 10;
  background-color: #5c755e;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
} 

#header h3 a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;

}

#header hr{
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Your other content is obscuring the side header

Comment: Your `h3` is going over the sidebar links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index:1;` to `.sideheader`.

```
.sideheader {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:-10px;
  z-index:1; /* add this */
}
```

Here is updated fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/3x00fzjf/5/.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
.sideheader {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:-10px;
}
```

by this:

```
.sideheader {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:-10px;
   z-index:1;
}
```

[Here is the updated **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3x00fzjf/3/)

Basically you add `z-index` to make it the top layer among the other elements, and hence it becomes clickable again :)